# Web API 2 - Error: "No type was found that matches the controller named 'resize'."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to just do a simple file upload API using Web API.

Here is the Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/resize")]
public class ResizeController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost, Route("api/resize/preserveAspectRatio")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> resizePreserveAspectRatio()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        int maxWidth = 100;
        int maxHeight = 100;

        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
        {
            var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
            var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            //Do whatever you want with filename and its binaray data.


        }

        return Ok();
    }


}
```

This is my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

When I POST a file with PostMan, here is the error I get:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:26303/api/resize/preserveAspectRatio'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'resize'."
}
```

This is not a dupe - was not able to find another article that addresses this specific combination.

Comment: Your route prefix already says "api/resize/" then in your controller Route you need not to mention it again. Just keep "preserveAspectRatio"

Comment: As @PM. mentions, your current route is `api/resize/api/resize/preserveAspectRatio`

Comment: Thanks - Hmmm I just changed it to `preserveAspectRatio` for the route and `api/resize` for the prefixRoute and it still gives the same error.  Any thoughts?  @PM  @zaitsman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This as you would expect is a routing issue. The comments have already identified that you have conflicts with your route and route prefix attributes resulting in the following route

```
api/resize/api/resize/preserveAspectRatio
```

being mapped to your action.

To get the desired route, you can either remove the prefix from the controller itself.

```
//removed prefix
public class ResizeController : ApiController {
    //Matches POST api/resize/preserveAspectRatio
    [HttpPost, Route("api/resize/preserveAspectRatio")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> resizePreserveAspectRatio() {
        //...removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Or Remove it from the route on the method

```
[RoutePrefix("api/resize")]
public class ResizeController : ApiController {
    //Matches POST api/resize/preserveAspectRatio
    [HttpPost, Route("preserveAspectRatio")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> resizePreserveAspectRatio() {
        //...removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Or override the route prefix by using tilde (`~`) on the method attribute

```
[RoutePrefix("api/resize")]
public class ResizeController : ApiController {
    //Matches POST api/resize/preserveAspectRatio
    [HttpPost, Route("~/api/resize/preserveAspectRatio")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> resizePreserveAspectRatio() {
        //...removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi - just tried your third option, `[RoutePrefix("api/resize")]` and `[HttpPost, Route("~/api/resize/preserveAspectRatio")]` and am getting the same error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Abr try the second option and see if that help. could be a conflict that the override has the same as the prefix.

Comment: Hmm tried that too @Nkosi, `[RoutePrefix("api/resize")]` and `[HttpPost, Route("preserveAspectRatio")]` and am getting the same error, `"MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'resize'."`

Comment: @Abr Based on what you have shown and the suggest solutions. that should work. Unless there is something else that you have not shown us that is causing the conflict. Is the project mixed. MVC and Web API?

Comment: Roger @Nkosi, weird.  No, it's a brand new Web API 2-only project in Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET + .NET Framework.  Is it possible it has something to do with the MIME type and the fact that it is a file upload?

Comment: @Abr to test that theory create another simple route, a GET probably and see if you can hit it.

Comment: Good idea @Nkosi - I tried this `[HttpGet, Route("test")]` as a new function in the same class and I get the exact same error.  Very strange indeed!  Appears to be affecting everything.

Comment: Check your startup and make sure the routing is being configured correctly.

Comment: OK - that was it.  I had some other projects in the solution that were conflicting.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @Abr If the problem was caused by code not present in the question you should either delete the question or edit it to include those details. Otherwise the question is off-topic as the problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto There were two problems actually.  The original question is actually still a problem.  I will remove the Update portion though.  The answer is useful and is correct, I just had a second problem beyond that.